# Identification of Primary Key used as Foreign Key elsewhere

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a primary key called `CustomerID` in the `CustomerTable` and there is a possibility of this PK being used as FK in various other tables (read more than 50) in the same database.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to identify in which all tables this PK is being used as FK.

Note: I'm using SQL Server

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ro.name as Referedtable, co.name as foreinKey,so.name as ParentTable
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
join sys.sysobjects co on co.id=fkc.constraint_object_id
join sys.sysobjects so on so.id=fkc.parent_object_id
join sys.sysobjects ro on ro.id=fkc.referenced_object_id
where ro.name='CustomerTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself and here's what I did.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [YourDBName].[sys].[foreign_keys]
  WHERE name LIKE '%CustomerID%'
```

Comment: there are two problems with your solution 1.) the name can be free defined 2.) think of a pattern like '%order%' having tables called "ordernumbers" "orderarticles" "borders" etc.

Comment: Thanks bummi. I realize the mistake now. Is there a way to optimize my solution?

Comment: SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_ID) FROM [sys].[foreign_keys] WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_ID)='CustomerTable'